# Geo Searching with Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

This is just a quick question. I am planning to change my search system to elasticsearch. If I send elasticsearch three pieces of information in my request:

- Long
- Lat
- Distance

And my elasticsearch results are tagged with the following information:

- Long
- Lat

Is it possible for me to only return results within that distance without needed any additional elasticsearch plugins? Is this functionality built into elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in three pretty simple steps. You must map the data (like setting up a database schema), insert the data, and then search for it (filter).

You must appropriately map the field so that it is recognized as a [`geo_point`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html). Note: If you wanted more flexibility to store other types of geolocations (e.g., polygons or linestrings), then you would want to map it as a [`geo_shape`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-shape-type.html).

```
{
  "mappings" : {
    "TYPE_NAME" : {
      "properties" : {
        "fieldName" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Once mapped, you can insert the location details using the [`point` type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-shape-type.html#_input_structure_2).

```
{
  "fieldName" : {
    "type" : "point",
    "coordinates" : [ longitude, latitude ]
  }
}
```

You can type it in differently to get the same effect, but perhaps more intuitively (rather than [ X, Y ], which is not the most common geospatial order).

```
{
  "fieldName" : {
    "type" : "point",
    "coordinates" : {
      "lat" : latitude,
      "lon" : longitude
    }
  }
}
```

Either way, it will represent the same thing (same goes for below in the filter).

Once you have mapped the field and started to insert points, then you can run a [`geo_distance` filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html#query-dsl-geo-distance-filter) to find points within the desired `distance`:

```
{
  "filtered" : {
    "query" : { "match_all" : {} },
    "filter" : {
      "geo_distance" : {
        "distance" : "10mi",
        "fieldName" : [ longitude, latitude ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```